# React redux middleware. Compare payload to store before dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I go about if I'd like to dispatch an action only when the payload has changed compared to the store? My main goal here is to prevent rerendering if the value in the store actually hasn't changed.

```
export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    posts.on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
      // dispatch only if payload is different from the data in store
      dispatch({
        type: DATA_PROPERTIES,
        payload: Object.keys(snapshot.val()),
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: This is actually the responsibility of the reducer, not the action-creator. Dispatching doesn't necessarily means re-render, which only happens if the state changes.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it not the responsibility of the middleware to act as a gatekeeper?

Comment: There's no need to prevent the action from reaching the reducer, because it's common for a reducer to conditionally update the state only if necessary (I actually think it's better if it does, because it portrays a better outline of the user flow when debugging). Generally speaking, action-creators should be pure whenever possible, and thunks should be used for async purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You have the access to to get State in the return function, throught redux-think. So you can do something like this

```
export function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    posts.on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
      // dispatch only if payload is different from the data in store
      //get Store state data here getState() will give you full state
      const data = getState().pathtoyourdata
     // write a helper function let says areSame and compare both the values
      if (areSame(data, snapshot.val())) {
        dispatch({
        type: DATA_PROPERTIES,
        payload: Object.keys(snapshot.val()),
      });
    }

    });
  };
}
```